# How local socket is differentiated?

Tags: process, sockets

In case of multiprocessor environment where IPC is implemented using a sockets How can we make sure each socket is identified.

For example In our environment we have around 14 process and each of them communicate with other process using unique number assigned to each process.

But how each socket is mapped to this unique number.

Comment: This sound more like a "#How did we implement our software" question than a general Ubuntu / Linux one. Could you please give some more details ?

Comment: It is a multi process system and they communicate with each other using the IPC module [implemented using a sockets].  this IPC is a shared lib. For establishing a communication with other process I just need to create a object for IPC module and share my id [id would be the enum assigned to my process] and the destination node id.                                                                                                                                  
 How is this mechanism being implemented where each local socket is differentiated using the enum assigned to it.

Comment: This can be done in many ways, but basically storing node-name and PID in a agreed place (database, file, shared-memory-segment, ...) then looking up the PID and use that as queue ID when a node-name is requested. But it can certainly be done in many other ways.